How do I publish my book free as a free to read website with webpages?
I saw a website where authors have published their entire book as a website. How can I also do it? Which website gives such tools?
http://www.feat.engineering/

How about a Gitlab or Github repo?

The source says the page was generated using bookdown 0.11.1 and GitBook 2.6.7. Bookdown itself is described here and seems like a reasonable option if you like R Markdown:

The bookdown package is built on top of R Markdown (http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com), and inherits the simplicity of the Markdown syntax (you can learn the basics in five minutes; see Section 2.1), as well as the possibility of multiple types of output formats (PDF/HTML/Word/…). It has also added features like multi-page HTML output, numbering and cross-referencing figures/tables/sections/equations, inserting parts/appendices, and imported the GitBook style (https://www.gitbook.com) to create elegant and appealing HTML book pages. This book itself is an example of how you can produce a book from a series of R Markdown documents, and both the printed version and the online version can look professional. You can find more examples at https://bookdown.org.

There are also other options, like BookML that's built on LaTeXML.

Thank you! This is very helpful.

There are various way to publish online your book source.
Furthermore to GitBook, you can choose PreTeXt, or if you familiar to programming Sphinx would be a good choice.
One benefit of Sphinx is you can use a free online hosting service.
ReadThedocs.
See some examples.

Abstract Algebra and Its applications : PreTeXt
GNU Scientific Library Manual : Sphinx

